# mysql query on left join where multiple value

Tags: mysql

Here is my sql data fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63178/1. Waht's wrong with my query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT curr.id,curr.curr_tittle, curr.curr_desc 
FROM  wp_curriculum curr LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_curriculum_topic WHERE curr_topic IN (4,12)) AS A ON A.curr_id = curr.id ORDER BY A.id
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: what result you expecting? or you want?

Comment: what result set you expect and what is going wrong..pls explain?

Comment: can i join these 2 tables : SELECT DISTINCT id,curr_tittle, curr_desc 
FROM  wp_curriculum WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT curr_id FROM wp_curriculum_category WHERE curr_category IN (2,3))

SELECT DISTINCT id,curr_tittle, curr_desc 
FROM  wp_curriculum WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT curr_id FROM wp_curriculum_topic WHERE curr_topic IN (4,12))

Comment: You meant to combine the result of the two query? If so, use UNION.

Comment: We don't know the structure of your table `wp_curriculum_category`... Also I think `curr_id` should be a foreign key.

Comment: thanks can u give me idea UNION using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for matching row from both the table then just replace `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`, otherwise your sql query is showing expected result for LEFT JOIN condition.

SQL Query with INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT curr.id,curr.curr_tittle, curr.curr_desc FROM  wp_curriculum curr INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_curriculum_topic WHERE curr_topic IN (4,12)) AS A ON curr.id = A.curr_id ORDER BY A.id
```

Comment: you can actually do it without using subquery.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT curr.id,curr.curr_tittle, curr.curr_desc 
FROM   wp_curriculum curr 
  INNER JOIN wp_curriculum_topicAS A 
   ON curr.id = A.curr_id 
WHERE a.curr_topic IN (4,12)
ORDER BY A.id`

Answer (score 0):

Your query works as expected. Could it be you are mixing ID and CURR_ID?